# No visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares the selector 'addX:andY'

Tags: objective-c, swift

We are trying to reference Swift methods inside an Objective-C implementation.

Swift class:

```
import Foundation
@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func sayHello() -> Void {
        print("hello");
    }

    func addX(x:Int, andY y:Int) -> Int {
     return x+y
    }
}
```

Objective-C implementation (Objective-c.m):

```
#import "ProductModuleName-Swift.h"
MySwiftClass* getData = [[MySwiftClass alloc]init];
[getData sayHello] //works
[getData addX:5 addY:5] //No visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares selector 'addX:addY'
```

The last line of code gives the following error:

> No visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares selector 'addX:addY'

Comment: Definition `...andY...` and call `...addY...` differ.

Comment: Please explain.

Comment: `addY:` != `andY:` Even the error message in the topic is not the same as in the code

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If you command-click on `"ProductModuleName-Swift.h"` in the Xcode
source file editor then you can see how the Swift methods are mapped to Objective-C.

In your case that would be

```
@interface MySwiftClass : NSObject
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)sayHello;
- (NSInteger)addXWithX:(NSInteger)x andY:(NSInteger)y;
@end
```

which is called as

```
MySwiftClass* getData = [[MySwiftClass alloc]init];
[getData sayHello];
NSInteger result = [getData addXWithX:5 andY:5];
```

A better Swift 3 method name might be

```
func add(x: Int, y:Int) -> Int
```

because `x` is already the argument (external) name of the first
parameter. You can also add an `@objc()` attribute to the Swift definition
to control the Objective-C name. For example, with

```
@objc(addX:andY:)
func add(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    return x+y
}
```

it would be called from Objective-C as

```
NSInteger result = [getData addX:5 andY:5];
```

Comment: The command-click tip on the "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" is very useful. I am still struggling on how to access a static swift function from objective c++

Comment: As an update, in Swift 4 we now need the @objc in front every Swift function you want to make available to Objective-C; including object variables.

Comment: I am also facing same problem : No visible @interface for 'EvrythngHelper' declares the selector  & i am using swift 4 , and trying to use swift code inside objective c++ class

Comment: This tip is pure Gold! Thanks.

Comment: Can not find the "ProductModuleName-Swift.h" file in the navigator nor in finder!? Can anybody tell me where to CMD + click to see the file!? THANKS!!!

Answer (score 27):

As @ekscrypto pointed out, in Swift 4 and later you need to annotate individual functions with `@objc`. Prior to that, a single, class-level `@objc` was enough.
Of course in Objective-C class you must add import of `NAME_PROJECT-swift.h`.
If your project name is Sample then you must add:

```
#import Sample-swift.h
```

And then:

**Swift 4 or Less**

```
@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    
    func sayHello(){
      //function
    }

    func addX(){
      //function
    }
}
```

**Swift 4 or Greater**

```
@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    
    @objc func sayHello(){
      //function
    }

    @objc func addX(){
      //function
    }
}
```

Comment: @objc is key to solving this problem.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had forgotten to add:

```
#import "MyProject-Swift.h"
```

Into the obj c file.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Jose Pose S, For Swift 4 or greater

```
@objc class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    
    @objc func sayHello(){
      //function
    }

    @objc func addX(){
      //function
    }
}
```

OR

```
@objcMembers
class MySwiftClass: NSObject {
    
    func sayHello(){
      //function
    }

    func addX(){
      //function
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use both `@objcMembers` and `@objc` on a class. If you want to automatically expose all non-private members to Objective-C then just use `@objcMembers`.