# Call Swift func from Objective-C with parameter

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I want to integrate a Swift class into an UIViewController class.
I think I made all settings correct. I have a class rURLTask:NSObject with a function:

```
@objc public func primer() {
    print("primer")
}
```

In my .swift file and can call it from my Objective-C-class with:

```
[URLTask primer];
```

and it prints nicely.
Another function is:

```
@objc public func ladeURL(url: URL?) {
    print("loadURL")
}
```

but this one I cannot call from Objective-C. I try to write:

```
NSURL* testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];    
[URLTask ladeURL:testURL];
```

I get the error:

> No visible @interface for 'rURLTask' declares the selector 'ladeURL:'

I think there is a very basic mistake. Using Objective-C in Swift 3 in another project worked well.

Comment: Control-click on the "project-Swift.h" file and check how the functions are imported to Swift. – Or try autocompletion.

Comment: See [swift 3 method in objective-c fails with no visible @interface for 'MySwiftClass' declares the selector 'addX:andY'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41080100/1187415) – the same approach works in your case.

Comment: `URLTask` is not a good name for a variable, in ObjectiveC or in Swift. Variable names should start with a _small letter_.

Answer (score 13):

The reason you cannot call

```
@objc public func ladeURL(url: URL?) {
    print("loadURL")
}
```

by saying

```
[URLTask ladeURL:testURL];
```

is that `ladeURL:` is *not the name of this method as far as Objective-C is concerned.* That is what the compiler means when it says that "No visible @interface for 'rURLTask' declares the selector `ladeURL:`".

Its name as far as Objective-C is concerned is `ladeURLWithUrl:`. That is because you have exposed the `url:` parameter name as an external label.

---

If it was important to you to be able to say

```
[URLTask ladeURL:testURL];
```

in Objective-C, you could have declared `ladeURL` like this:

```
@objc public func ladeURL(_ url: URL?) {
    print("loadURL")
}
```

See the underscore? That hides the external label of the parameter.

---

Another solution, allowing you to keep the `url:` external label, would be to declare the Objective-C name as part of the `objc` attribution:

```
@objc(ladeURL:) public func ladeURL(url: URL?) {
    print("loadURL")
}
```

That says to the compiler: "I know you would *like* to translate the name of this method into Objective-C as `ladeURLwithUrl:`, but don't; translate it as `ladeURL:` instead."

Comment: Some tips for how Swift and Objective-C see one another's method names are to be found in my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_methods

Comment: Excellent answer (As usual.) Voted.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks. It did occur to me to mention that the rules here (for translation of method names between the two languages) have changed over time; I think in Swift 2 the OP's original code would have worked, am I remembering right? But I decided it wasn't worth flogging that horse.

Answer (score 3):

When you import the class to OC , the name of the method written in swift is translated concatenated with the **withParameterType** , as prime 
method

```
@objc public func primer() {
  print("primer")
}
```

has no parameters it can be called like this

```
[URLTask primer];
```

but this

```
@objc public func ladeURL(url: URL?) {
   print("loadURL")
}
```

is translated to

```
[URLTask ladeURLWithUrl:<#NSURL#>];
```