# iOS Charts subclass Markerview use Swift always Build Error in "xxx-Swift.h"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios-charts

MarkerView is in **"Charts"** framework, When i subclass MarkerView with swift and it will occur **Build Error** in **“Project-Swift.h”** file， **“Project-Swift.h”** auto generate by **Xcode**.

In **"TestMV.swift"** file:

```
import UIKit

import Charts

class TestMV: MarkerView {

}
```

In **"ProjectName-Swift.h"** file:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC9KCTFunFit6TestMV")

@interface TestMV : ChartMarkerView

- (nonnull instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 

OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

- (nullable instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder * _Nonnull)coder 

OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

@end
```

In **"Charts"** framework

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics
import AppKit

@objc(ChartMarkerView)
open class MarkerView: NSUIView, IMarker {
     open var offset: CGPoint = CGPoint()

     @objc open weak var chartView: ChartViewBase?

     open func offsetForDrawing(atPoint point: CGPoint) -> CGPoint
     {
        .......
     }
 }
```

**TestMV** subclass **Markerview** in **"TestMV.swift"**
[image]

Build always error in **"ProjectName-Swift.h"**
[image]

Markerview in **"Charts"** Framework
[image]

Comment: have you imported `ChartMakerView` dependency?  Or might you need to create `ChartMakerView` class first

Comment: Please include the code as text instead of image. That way search engines can index it and screenreaders work too.

Comment: @BDL 
thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @Siarhei I have re-added the relevant information, I do not know whether it is clear

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `@interface TestMV : ChartMarkerView` to `@interface TestMV : MarkerView` as that is how it was defined in your TestMV class.

For future reference, [a similar question can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080100/swift-3-method-in-objective-c-fails-with-no-visible-interface-for-myswiftclass).

Comment: @interface TestMV : ChartMarkerView, this is auto generate in "ProjectName-Swift.h" by Xcode, I can't modify

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Charts/Charts-Swift.h>
```